# How to create dynamic route in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I have setup gatsby project using this [**link**](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start). It is working correctly.

Now I know how to create route by defining the component inside the **`pages`** folder. But now I have a new challenge I need to create one dynamic route so that  I can pass my **`id`** in it (Just like `reactjs`).

```
<Route path: "/path/:id"/>
```

How do I do that in gatsby?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell gatsby that a path should be dynamic. From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/):

```
// gatsby-node.js
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/app/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

and then you can use dynamic routing in `src/pages/app.js`

```
import { Router } from "@reach/router"

const SomeSubPage = props => {
  return <div>Hi from SubPage with id: {props.id}</div>
}

const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Link to="/app/1">First item</Link>{" "}
    <Link to="/app/2">Second item</Link>{" "}

    <Router>
      // ...dynamic routes here
      <SomeSubPage path="/app/:id" />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)

export default App
```

Everything that goes to `/app/*` will be handled dynamically now. You should find your id as usual in the props.

Have a look at their authentication example https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/simple-auth

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I remove `/app` from my route?

Comment: Yes, sure! Adjust the config in `gatsby-node.js` (page.path.match(...))

Comment: I tried that. But not sure how do I remove the `/app` and only put only `/`. Can you please guide me

Comment: In my humble opinion that is not how gatsby is supposed to work. If you want a fully dynamic page, have a look create-react-app. Gatsby is a static site generator that generates pages from static content. It can handle dynamic content, but if you asked me that's not the main purpose.

Comment: Gatsby is more than a static site generator, you can build apps with it just like you used to do with CRA

Comment: Hey, do you have any GitHub repo for just to know about how to add external CSS and js files in the gatsby project?

Comment: can I use parameters in `createPage`? like: 


createPage({
    path: "/blog/:blogId/:slug",
    matchPath: "/blog/:blogId/:slug",
    component: path.resolve("src/components/layouts/BlogLayout.jsx"),
  })

Comment: Don't have to touch `gatsby-node.js` at all. Just need to add a file with square brackets in the pages folder. For example users/[id].js.

Answer (score 8):

You can use square brackets `([ ])` in the file path to mark any dynamic segments of the URL. For example, in order to edit a user, you might want a route like `/user/:id` to fetch the data for whatever id is passed into the URL.

`src/pages/users/[id].js` will generate a route like `/users/:id`
`src/pages/users/[id]/group/[groupId].js` will generate a route like `/users/:id/group/:groupId`

Reference: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api#creating-client-only-routes

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: This approach also works on Gatsby v4.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`. It uses `matchPath`. For more info check

1. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-internals-terminology/#matchpath
2. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths/

Comment: not really, I don't think this gives the flexibility of dynamic paths, just making easier to add new ones. See:  "Use this plugin to simplify creating a “hybrid” Gatsby app with both statically rendered pages as well as “client-paths”."

Answer (score 2):

This answer is Super late, but for anyone in the future who is faced with this problem, I have a simpler solution.

In Gatsby terms it's called a [Splat Route](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/#splat-routes).

For examples, If you want some page "domain.com/profile/[id]", where id can be any number, which will be used to display different data inside the website, you should name your page as [...id].

Now inside the page you can access this id as

```
const ProfilePage = (props) => <div>This page is for id number {props.params.id}</div>
```

Note: Don't miss the 3 dots, that is what signifies a splat route in gatsby.