# Gatsby createpages dynamic path

Tags: gatsby

```
createPage({
    path: `product/${node.id}/[any-matching-string]`,
    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/productDetail.js`),
    context: {
      productId: node.id
    },
  })
```

path: product/${node.id}/**[any-matching-string]**,

How do i achieve such path?
url: someurl/product/id/[any string]

Comment: Do you want to create a dynamic route at `product`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756994/how-to-create-dynamic-route-in-gatsby

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic route in gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756994/how-to-create-dynamic-route-in-gatsby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.According to those two comments, it is possible duplicate of those questions. But i slightly wanted different settings.

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions    
  if (page.path === "/") {
    page.matchPath = "/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

This is what i exactly wanted.

And in my index.js page, i have to use reach router.
If anyone need more details, comment here. I will share the complete code.

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of using gatsby?

Comment: How? I will not accept my answer if there is a problem on this. I actually discussed with Gatsby team on github. I did not get any objection from them. Can you explain a little more about the problem in using this?