# How to create routes with dynamic params in gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'd like to be able to create a route that has a dynamic param like so:

`http://localhost:8000/verification/:id`

where id is some sort of token or guid that I can then access
in my page component.

How might I be able to do this?

Comment: Try [how to create a dynamic route in gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756994/how-to-create-dynamic-route-in-gatsby)

Comment: People need to start looking into documentation and older questions first, before creating a new one...