# Create pages in gastby dynamically when you dont know the path

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to create dynamic pages in gatsby but I don't know what the full url name would be.

```
  createPage({
    path: '/account/orders/:id',
    matchPath: '/account/orders/:id',
    component: path.resolve('./src/templates/order.tsx'),
  });
```

I thought the code written would be okay to visit page with any value of 'id' but while building the development bundle it gives an error
`account\orders\:id contains invalid WIN32 path characters`

The ':id' value can be anything so I dont want to use looping method to create the page. What could be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamic route in gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756994/how-to-create-dynamic-route-in-gatsby)

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that:

- You don't want to loop through pages
- You will never know the value of the `id`

Your only chance is to use [client-only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/) through the file system route API.

In your case, assuming that your "unknown" page will be under `/account/orders` you should create a folder structure such: `src/pages/account/orders/[...].js`. The `[...].js` notation stands for the file system route for an `undefined` value.

In the [`...].js` file you can just create something like:

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Profile from "../components/Profile"
import Default from "../components/Default"
import CustomOrderComponent from "../components/CustomOrderComponent"

const Orders = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Router basepath="/account/orders">
        <Profile path="/profile" />
        <CustomOrderComponent path='/:id' />
        <Default path="/" />
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Orders
```

From the docs:

> Briefly, when a page loads, Reach Router looks at the `path` prop of
> each component nested under `<Router />`, and chooses one to render
> that best matches `window.location` (you can learn more about how
> routing works from the [`@reach/router` documentation](https://reach.tech/router/api/Router)). In the
> case of the `/orders/profile` path, the `Profile` component will be
> rendered, as its prefix matches the base path of `/orders`, and the
> remaining part is identical to the child’s path.

In the above scenario, `CustomOrderComponent` will render your variable `id` (`:id`).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this without creating new page?

Comment: You need a page to show something to the users that go to `:id`. Can you describe better your scenario?

Comment: The error that page was not opening was only with the windows machine, it worked properly when opened with ubuntu, Thank you for the help.